# Does Cosmos DB return updated fields in its change feed similar to the way Mongo DB does in its Change Events

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Does Cosmos DB return updated fields in its change feed similar to the way Mongo DB does in its Change Events

Below is a change stream response document from Mongo DB. The updateDescription includes the updateFields. Does Cosmos DB provide a similar feature or are you expected to roll out your own implementation by comparing the previous documents to find out what fields have changed.

```
 {
   _id : { <BSON Object> },
   "operationType" : "<operation>",
   "fullDocument" : { <document> },
   "ns" : {
      "db" : "<database>",
      "coll" : "<collection>"
   },
   "to" : {
      "db" : "<database>",
      "coll" : "<collection>"
   },
   "documentKey" : { "_id" : <value> },
   "updateDescription" : {
      "updatedFields" : { <document> },
      "removedFields" : [ "<field>", ... ],
      "truncatedArrays" : [
         { "field" : <field>, "newSize" : <integer> },
         ...
      ]
   },
   "clusterTime" : <Timestamp>,
   "txnNumber" : <NumberLong>,
   "lsid" : {
      "id" : <UUID>,
      "uid" : <BinData>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB does support updates in the API for MongoDB change streams: Change streams in [Azure Cosmos DB’s API for MongoDB | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/change-streams?tabs=javascript#current-limitations)
Change streams in Azure Cosmos DB’s API for MongoDB
Learn how to use change streams n Azure Cosmos DB’s API for MongoDB to get the changes made to your data.

The insert, update, and replace operations types are currently supported. However, the delete operation or other events are not yet supported.